# Floorball stick size

Tags: equipment, floorball

Online sources tend to advice a floorball stick to end a few (2-4) centimeters above the navel when held straight vertically in front of the body.

However, in a team I recently joined (a reasonably good amateur team) almost all players use a stick that is longer (about 5-10cm above the navel).

Trying out sticks myself I also prefer the "too long" stick. But this could simply be because I have recently been playing which such a stick and have gotten used to it.

Is the advice outdated or wrong?
Is it important to learn to play with a stick within the recommended length range?

P.S.: I am 1.82 cm. I believe a 96cm stick would be recommended. A 100cm or even 104 cm stick seems to fit me better.